# How does Ray handles a number of jobs higher than the number of resources?

Tags: ray

Pretty basic question, but I wasn't able to find the answer in the docs.
I am developing a computationally intensive application in Python and I'm employing Ray to parallelize computation. I only use remote functions (thus no Actors) and I have 40 cores available.

What happens when the main script sends a number of tasks higher than 40? Is Ray able to handle it or should I always control the number of tasks in order to keep it under the number of available cores?

Answer (score 2):

In this scenario, Ray will queue the tasks, and run them as CPUs become available.

For example,

```
import ray 
import time

ray.init(num_cpus=10)

@ray.remote
def outer_task():
 return ray.get([inner_task.remote() for _ in range(20)])

@ray.remote
def inner_task():
 return time.sleep(1)

ray.get([outer_task.remote() for _ in range(20)])
```

in this scenario, there are 420 tasks which each require a CPU. Ray will queue and run these tasks, so that at most 10 tasks are running at the same time, and will make sure they all finish (in roughly 40 seconds).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Do you have a reference in the docs for this? I would like to understand more deeply this matter, because I noticed that, when giving Ray too many tasks to manage, sometimes crashes are encountered (I work with a cluster on Azure Databricks).

Comment: They've got one reference at https://docs.ray.io/en/master/ray-core/patterns/limit-running-tasks.html .. but that's to limit the number of tasks for a single not. Not limit the number of tasks globally, which sounds more important (unless you only have one job).